# Estimate Memory Consumption of Android Application or Activity

Tags: android, performance, memory-management

For an algorithm, you can be able to compute the time complexity to determine its efficiency. Is there any general framework, principles that can be used to compute or estimate the memory consumption required by an android application or even just an activity?

I looked at the possible duplicate question but it doesn't provide a general framework or way of computation for memory usage as explained in the comment reply below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

Comment: @MatthewShearer, I looked at that post before and it isn't what I am looking for. I am looking for something more theoretical which can be applied like the big O notation but this time for memory or some general principles that if it has variables, objects, loops, etc. then it memory consumption would estimate to ...